# Sizing of thumb of mat slider

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular9, angular10

I am using mat slider in my angular application. Stackblitz link is

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-custom-slider?file=app%2Fslider-overview-example.ts

The problem I am facing is whenever I click on thumb to slide the circle becomes bigger. How can I keep that circle in it's original size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
::ng-deep .mat-slider-thumb {
  transform: scale(0.7) !important;
}
```

There are multiple ways to do it. This is the one I could come up with now.

Comment: nops this code is not working. Circle still increasing in size on touch or sliding

Comment: @RAZZZ Sorry! I posted the wrong `css` in here. I have updated the answer and tested the same in your stackblitz link.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-custom-slider-kwcx1v?file=app/slider-overview-example.css

Comment: @RAZZZ thanks for accepting the answer. You could mark it useful if you want.